# Не подтягиваются стили при работе в Docker

Tags: php, html, css, ubuntu, docker

Класс .inde не получает стиль из main.css.
Файл index.php и main.css находятся в одной директории

*Настройки локалки для ubuntu*

**index.php**

```
<?php 

echo "HI";

 ?>

 <hr>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<div class="inde">Some stupid text</div>
```

**main.css**

```
.inde{
    margin-top: 100px;

}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
      - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

      - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
      - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log

  php-fpm:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./public:/application/public
```

**default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    root /docker_with_php-master/public;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для **nginx** также добавьте **volume** на директорию с файлами:

```
      - ./public:/application/public
```

После чего в конфигурации нжинкса установите основную директорию:

```
    root /application/public;
```